# Spring-jdbc-4.0.5.release: Set DriverManagerDataSource connection timeout programmatically

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

I noticed SQL connection is closed after 30 minutes so am trying to increase it to 60 minutes. Below is my Spring Datasource configuration class for Sql server 2008  and am trying to set the connectiontimeout as `ds.getConnectionProperties().put("socketTimeout", jdbcsocketTimeout);` but am getting `Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'` error while starting the application.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class JpaConfiguration {

    @Value("${jdbc.driverClassName}")
    String jdbcDriverClassName;
    @Value("${jdbc.url}")
    String jdbcUrl;
    @Value("${jdbc.username}")
    String jdbcUsername;
    @Value("${jdbc.password}")
    String jdbcPassword;
    @Value("${jdbc.socketTimeout}")
    int jdbcsocketTimeout;

    @Bean
    public javax.sql.DataSource remoteDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource(jdbcUrl, jdbcUsername, jdbcPassword);
        ds.setDriverClassName(jdbcDriverClassName);
        System.out.println("jdbcsocketTimeout "+jdbcsocketTimeout);
        //ds.getConnectionProperties().put("socketTimeout", jdbcsocketTimeout);
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> jpaProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();      
        props.put("hibernate.dialect", SQLServer2008Dialect.class.getName());       
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();      
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.SQL_SERVER);     
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lef.setDataSource(this.remoteDataSource());
        lef.setPackagesToScan(getClass().getPackage().getName());
        lef.setJpaPropertyMap(this.jpaProperties());
        lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(this.jpaVendorAdapter());
        return lef;
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me to set connection timeout in the above class?

Comment: I think you should use connection pooling for that, and why don't you use hikari datasource if you are using spring boot 2.x

Comment: This is not a spring boot application, it's a spring integration application

Comment: even though ` DriverManagerDataSource` is not connection pool, you have to use connection pooling to set the properties